# Strange / unstable behaviour on CreatePivotTable()

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing VBA code to automate some processes in Excel and I am encountering a very strange behavior for which I have not been able to find documentation / help.

I have a procedure `MAJ_GF` that first executes function `GF.Update`, checks the result, and then launches procedure `GF.Build` (which basically takes the data obtained by `GF.Update` from different worksheets and does a bunch of stuff with it).

At some point, this "bunch of stuff" requires using a pivot table, so `GF.Build` contains the following line:

```
Set pvt = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, _
   "'source_GF'!R1C1:R" & j & "C" & k).CreatePivotTable("'TCD_GF'!R4C1", "GFTCD1")
```

**The strange behavior is this:**

- when I run `MAJ_GF`, VBA properly executes `GF.Update`, then launches `GF.Build`, and stops at the line described above complaining "Bad argument or procedure call"
- when I manually run `GF.Update`, then manually run `GF.Build`, everything goes smoothly and `GF.Build` does what it has to do from beginning to end with no errors
- even stranger, when I set a break-point on the incriminated line, run `MAJ_GF` then VBA pauses on the line as expected, and when I say "Continue"... it just continues smoothly and with no errors !

I turned this around and around and around, double-checked the value of every variable, and this just makes no sense.

Ideas anybody?

Comment: What is your excel version? Code looks nice, so without actual file it will be a very wild guess....

Comment: I use Excel 2007. There's really nothing extraordinary with the data and given the behavior (same code working _and_ not working with the same data), I suspect it's something linked to execution conditions, but I can't see what's the difference between a combined execution from a procedure and the stand-alone execution from console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few ideas come to my mind:

1. There's still some update going on in the background. Try `DoEvents` and `Application.Wait` before the line you mentiond
2. Also check, if any data connections are able to update in the background - if so disable the background refresh
3. Very rarely (usually in older version and when involving Charts), unhiding the Excel window (in case you used `Application.Visible = False` and enabling `ScreenUpdating` helped..
4. Are you using any "exotic" references/add-ins? Disable them and see if the problem persists.
5. Try restarting your machine

Not that I'm too optimistic that either will solve your problem - but give it a try! Best of luck!

Comment: +1 for the summarized bunch of suggestions. Support all of them!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions : I tried (2) is not applicable, (1) (3) and (5) did not solve the problem. One thing I omitted : `GF.Update` (so not the procedure generating the error but the one executed prior to that) uses functions from an XLL declared using `Private Declare Function ...`. I'll see if I can find a workaround and keep y'all posted.

Comment: @PeterAlbert Thumbs up for the "exotic reference" explanation, should have thought of that... so yeah that treats the symptoms :) What's annoying is that I don't know what's going on under the hood when I run the referenced functions that would cause such a mess. I guess I'll just try to work around it !